# OpenWeatherMap for 3 days with jquery

Tags: jquery, weather-api, openweathermap

So I would like to get the following data:

Only for one city, for example London
Today temperature
Tomorrow min and max temp
After tomorrow min and max temp

Then I grab those values and append it to the html. The question is, how do I filter the data received from the json request? Here is my sample code, I already have the data for today temp, but how do I filter for the next days min and max temp?

Thank you so much

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {


function getWeather(callback) {
    var weather = 'http://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&units=metric';
    jQuery.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: weather,
      success: callback
    });
}

// get data:
getWeather(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.list[0].main.temp);
    console.log(data.list[0].main.temp_min);
    console.log(data.list[0].main.temp_max);
});

// append data to html
jQuery('span.customWeather').text('weather here!');


});
```

Comment: read the api, get the data structure and then build your code to parse it out. you get data for today to console, do you get tomorrows ? output the whole data set to console and look for the next day set.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to look for that data in the console. can you give me just an example for tomorrow data? Thank you

Comment: Down voted for not doing research, question answered on how to do research.

Comment: @alexmac SO is one of the first results regarding almost any problem one has. Even IF the OP could have found the answer, it is still meaningful to provide an answer on SO. Even so more if the answer is made with additionaly background information others might not have or which are not easily found when searching the web. This is what makes SO one of the best platforms for finding important information on how to implement something not only in a working but also in a clean and efficiant way. d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't have the data set - but - take the url to the JSON data open it in a browser just post it in the window.

I did this and here is a snipet of what I got (without reading the document for the site)

{"cod":"200","message":0.3729,"city":{"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji","coord":{"lon":138.933334,"lat":34.966671},"country":"JP","population":0},"cnt":41,"list":[{"dt":1394992800,"main":{"temp":-6.78,"temp_min":-6.78,"temp_max":-6.78,"pressure":935.65,"sea_level":1036.67,"grnd_level":935.65,"humidity":73,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":0.71,"deg":128.005},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2014-03-16 18:00:00"},{"dt":1395003600,"main":{"temp":-8.05,"temp_min":-8.05,"temp_max":-8.05,"pressure":936.88,"sea_level":1038.77,"grnd_level":936.88,"humidity":72,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":0.61,"deg":175.004},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2014-03-16 21:00:00"},{"dt":1395014400,"main":

I searched and hunted and found a date reference with the Mark 1 search engine called the human Eye.

there  I found the variable dt_txt 'dt_txt":"2014-03-16 18:00:00".

you can then access the data in that array.  The date javascript functions and array access is documented online and I won't repeat them, this is searching for examples you can find.

It took me less than 3 minutes to find that each row of data is marked with a date time tag.

Comment: I should add the other way to get the data you want [API SPEC](http://openweathermap.org/API)

Answer (score 1):

I hit a similar snag in that I was including "daily" in the url as used in the example at openweathermap.org/forecast

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&units=metric&cnt=7

That style of url returns a very terse json object with no "dt_txt" giving the forecast date, just the confusing (to newbies) unix time number which isn't the applicable day for the forecast, but the timestamp for when the data was retrieved from the weather station.

By leaving out the "daily", ie

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&units=metric&cnt=7

brings a far more verbose json response which includes dt_txt.